# Calculate $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}H_i\cdot i$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, summation

Calculate $$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}H_i\cdot i$$
Where $$H_n = 1+\frac{1}{2}+...+\frac{1}{n} $$

### My try

I am interested in using the formula from my lecture:
$$ \sum_{i=a}^{b}f(k)\cdot\Delta g(k) = f(b)g(b)-f(a)g(a)-\sum_{i=a}^{b}\Delta f(k)\cdot g(k+1) $$
where $$ \Delta f(k) = f(k+1)-f(k) $$

So in my case I have
$$ f(k) = H_k \wedge \Delta g(k) = k $$
so I can take
$$ \Delta f(k) = \frac{1}{k+1} \wedge g(k) = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} k = \frac{(n-1)n}{2} $$

Ok so I can start calculating:
$$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}H_i\cdot i =\\ f(n-1)g(n-1)-0-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{k+1} \cdot \frac{k(k+1)}{2} =\\ H_{n-1}\cdot \frac{(n-2)(n-1)}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{(n-1)n}{2} = \\
\frac{n-1}{2}\cdot \left( H_{n-1}(n-2)-\frac{n}{2} \right)
\\ \frac{n-1}{2}\cdot \left( (H_n - \frac{1}{n})(n-2)-\frac{n}{2} \right)$$

But the answer in book is
$$ \frac{n(n-1)(2H_n-1)}{4} $$ which is not equal to my result

PS: I can't use  $ \int $

Comment: Can you subtract them and simplify to try to see where you might've made a mistake? At a glance it looks like whatever mistake you made should be relatively small (perhaps a fencepost error in the setup for the summation by parts).

Comment: Yeah, in a format more like what you wrote the correct answer is $\frac{n-1}{2}(nH_n-n/2)$ so the $-1/n$ and the $-2$ should both not be there, tracing those back should help...

Comment: @rtybase they have used $ \int $ - didn't have that on my lecture.

Comment: There are 2 answers there ...

Comment: The second one use double sum - as I mentioned - I want to use formula from lecture

Comment: @Ian I wonder if I correctly use that formula... because in calculation I don't see mistake...

Comment: @VirtualUser, you mentioned <<On my lecture I had that formula>> and not <<I am interested in using the formula from my lecture>>. Please update the text to make this obvious.

Comment: done @rtybase, sorry for confusion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By my calculation, the surface term (sorry, physics lingo) should actually be $f\left(b+1\right)g\left(b+1\right)-f\left(a\right)g\left(a\right)$. Cancelling the red terms below, $$\sum_{i=a}^{b}\left(f\left(k\right)\Delta g\left(k\right)+g\left(k+1\right)\Delta f\left(k\right)\right)\\=\sum_{i=a}^{b}\left(\color{red}{f\left(k\right)g\left(k+1\right)}-f\left(k\right)g\left(k\right)+g\left(k+1\right)f\left(k+1\right)\color{red}{-g\left(k+1\right)f\left(k\right)}\right)\\=f\left(b+1\right)g\left(b+1\right)-f\left(a\right)g\left(a\right).$$So instead we get $\frac{n(n-1)}{4}(2H_n-1)$ as required.

Comment: Your right,  I misunderstood the material from the lecture (this formula was not given explicitly) - thanks for help!